# Update html attribute in java

Tags: java, html-parsing

I want to remove style attibute and replace it with unique class in html in java.

Input html:

```
<div style="A">
 <div style="B">
</div>
<div style="C">
</div>
```

Output updated html:

```
<div class="class01">
<div class="class02">
</div>
<div class="class03">
</div>
```

Please tell me how can I do it easly in java!

I am trying to get using code available on:

```
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/ParseHTML.htm
```

If you know any other good way, then please tell me! I don't have rnd time and have to done soon.

Comment: you can do it in client part using jquery? why in java?

Comment: @Nurlan I can do it on client side, but my client told me do it on backend side :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. If you use [jSoup](http://jsoup.org), you can

```
Elements es = doc.select("div");
for(int i=0; i < es.size(); i++){
  if(es.get(i).attr("style").equals("A"))
     es.get(i).addClass("class01").removeAttr("style");

  //similarly for other cases
}
```

I guess there are better ways to do this in jSoup, but this is the quickest I could do.

refer: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-attributes